# Saving and loading UIImage in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, load, uiimage, save

I am having a headache working out what's wrong with my app. I am trying to save and load UIImages, simple right? Seems not so.

I have a class with these methods to save, load and delete an image with a unique string. Just how I like it, nice and simple. Here is the class:

**imageSavedLoad.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface imageSaveLoad : NSObject

- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image forKey:(NSString*)imageName;
- (void)removeImage:(NSString*)fileName;
- (UIImage*)loadImage:(NSString*)imageName;

@end
```

**imageSaveLoad.m:**

```
#import "imageSaveLoad.h"


@implementation imageSaveLoad

//saving an image
- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)image forKey:(NSString*)imageName
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
    NSLog(@"image saved");
}

//removing an image
- (void)removeImage:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", fileName]];
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath: fullPath error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"image removed");
}

//loading an image
- (UIImage*)loadImage:(NSString*)imageName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", imageName]];
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
}

@end
```

Where I want to save, load or delete an image I import the class: `#import "imageSaveLoad.h"`

Then I create an instance of it and call the required methods (here I save):

```
imageSaveLoad *imgSL = [[imageSaveLoad alloc] init];
[imgSL saveImage:photoImgView.image forKey:@"yourPhoto"];
```

Then in another view/class where I want to retrieve the image:

```
imageSaveLoad *imgSL = [[imageSaveLoad alloc] init];
yourImgView.image = [imgSL loadImage:@"yourPhoto"];
```

But `yourImgView` displays nothing, blank.

So where am I going wrong? I have checked all `IBOutlet` connections and that all the code is being called. Is there a problem with the methods I am using?

Comment: please, log the following for us: the full path where you've saved the `UIImage`, the load path where you want to load the `UIImage` back from, and please make sure to check after the saving: is the image file in the `Documents` folder?

Comment: You should provide an error and look at the return code for [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; - you are just assuming success. Supposidly the Documents directory is for iCloud now and you may need to use the caches directory for this purpose.

Comment: Those methods could be class methods. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving image, try by replacing this line :

```
 [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
```

With

```
 [imageData writeToFile:fullpath atomically:YES];
```